# Write over a htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

An .htaccess file is uploaded to a directory via ftp, the owner and group of the said file is then generally the ftp user and / or root.

If the said directory had file permissions set to 0777 would it at all be possible for a remote script to write over the said .htaccess file, or would every attempt always be blocked as the owner and group of the .htaccess file is the ftp user (and the root), and the hacker (depending on which port they were attempting to enter through) will not be logged into the server as the ftp user (and hopefully not the root user either).

The reason I ask is because I have the need for a directory to be permissions 0777 and am concerned that the .htaccess file (which prevents scripts from running in the said directory) could simply be overwritten meaning the said server would be vunerable to attack.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't set 0777 permissions on a directly containing a .htaccess file.  In that situation I would probably advise moving the files requiring 0777 permissions into a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be vulnerable to an attack if a script has write access to that folder regardless. Here's an example from a true story on a friend's server:

1. Old version of TimThumb allowed files to be uploaded maliciously
2. The file uploaded was Syrian Shell, a script used to decrypt user permissions and begin creating new files
3. Access was given to the intruder and the server was effectively turned into a host for a phishing site.

I highly recommend you take a look at your structure. Move write access to a subdirectory. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, well i'm trying to write a CMS system for a friend who is a webdesigner.

Comment: What's the uploading for? if it's images and hosted files, a lot of CMS's have a specified folder for uploads. like wordpress: /wp-content/uploads/file.jpg